# Sharepoint: Create a task for 2 users and continue workflow if just one aprove the task

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I do not know if it's possible but I need in a workflow create a task for 2 users and if only 1 of them approve the flow should continue. The problem so far is that he always waits for the approval of the 2 to continue the workflow.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If you use the Out of the Box Approval workflow you can specify in a parallel workflow how many approvals need to be entered for the item to be approved.  If you enter 2 approver addresses and set it up so that approval only needs one then it will
 be approved when the first person approves it.  Workflow tasks for all other workflow instances on the item will be cancelled.  I don't remember the exact name of the setting but its toward the bottom of the Initiation form that comes up when you
 configure the workflow on a document libary.

[Multiple approvers with only one approval required](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c612c055-6eeb-45bd-ab15-65ab94386b3b/multiple-approvers-with-only-one-approval-reqired?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)